# Adding Environment Variables to Eclipse shortcut

Tags: eclipse, windows, environment-variables

Is it possible to set an environment variable for the current run of Eclipse ( RAD )?

Here is my situation

I have RAD 8.5 and RAD 9.0 installed on my box.  It stopped working all of a sudden last week.  It wouldn't even come up.  When I checked the logs, both the versions had below error in the logs

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.mercury.ftjadin.hooks.interfaces.WToolkitHookQTJA
```

After some research I also found out that it is caused by HP's product that was installed on my box ( It was done as a corporate push and I wasn't even aware of it ).

Further research also revealed that there are about 4 environment variables that have a conflict with Eclipse and should be removed / blanked out for RAD to work.  This will of course cause the HP product to not work.

So, I was wondering if there is a way to set these to blank in ***eclipse.ini*** file for each of the RADs or as part of the shorcut of RAD which is

```
C:\Software\RAD90\eclipse.exe -product com.ibm.rational.rad.product.v9.ide -showlocation -nosplash -clean
```

but not blank them out in the Environment Variables definition

This way, I will be able to use both the products without having to save the variable values between RAD and HP Mercury product usages and do not have to do a copy / paste every time which is prone to user errors / mistakes.

Hope the question makes sense.  Please let me know, if I need to clarify anything.

Comment: How about creating a batch script that sets the variables you need and then starts Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

You can start eclipse (for example RAD) from eclipse (for example a minimal Java plugin development) and in that case, you have the option to set the environment variables you want to use.
You have to set the target environment to the RAD instance and create a run configuration with the proper environment.
I know, this is less than ideal, but should work.
Another option would be the [unsetting env variables](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/630/using-variables-in-windows-batch-files/) (locally) in a batch file:

```
set var=
```

Though I do not know whether it would work or not.

Answer (score 0):

[This page helped my situation](https://community.hpe.com/t5/Unified-Functional-Testing/UFT-causing-issues-with-RDz-Eclipse-based-after-install/td-p/6811877)

Instead of playing with registry I took an option of batch

These suggestions will allow to work around this situation even with the environment variables in place and with corresponding values. Note: Conflicting application will not be recognized in a java context because it is being excluded from the java support mechanism.

Impact: Excludes Add-ins support from hooking to conflicting application executable via Windows Registry Editor
Requirement: The application must be started by an EXE file, except `Java.exe/Javaw.exe/jpnlauncher.exe`

Instructions:

a. Locate the executable filename of the application conflicting with add-in(s) support. Either use the Task Manager or the Microsoft Process Explorer.

b. Open Windows Registry Editor.

c. Navigate to: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Mercury Interactive\JavaAgent\Modules`
For 32bits applications on Windows x64:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Mercury Interactive\JavaAgent\Modules
```

d. Create a DWORD value with the name of the conflicting software executable filenmae and set the value to 0.

2. Impact: Does not load Java Support for specific launched session

Requirement: Application be launched using a batch file
Instructions:

a. Create a batch file (.bat)

b. Copy/Paste below coding before executing launching of Java application.

```
@ECHO off
Set _JAVA_OPTIONS=
Set JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=
Set IBM_JAVA_OPTIONS=
```

This approach will disable the java environment variables for the run session of the .bat file. Once batch execution closes, environment variables changes are lost.